# Регулярные выражения для парсинга HTML․

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте любители регулярных выражений

Есть HTML код:

```
<h2>Победители:</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="image">
      <img src="https://pp.com/QEOfSop877c.jpg">     
      <i>1</i>
    </span>
    <a class="name" href="https://vk.com/13156464" target="_blank">Иван</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <span class="image">
      <img src="https://pp.com/QEOfSop877c.jpg">     
      <i>1</i>
    </span>
    <a class="name" href="https://vk.com/13156464" target="_blank">Иван</a>
  </li>   
</ul>
<h2>Конец:</h2>
```

Нужно найти и заменить ul список на другой

Вот что я сделал PHP

```
$content = preg_replace('/<h2>Победители:</h2>(.*)<h2>Конец</h2>/', '<h2>Победители:</h2>НОВЫЙ СПИСОК<h2>Конец</h2>', $content);
echo $content;
```

Но к сожалению выражение `(.*)` "сьедает" все , в том числе и код идущий после `<h2>Конец</h2>`

Comment: Видимо надо уменьшать жадность захвата, `.*?`. А вообще не дело разбирать html регулярками. лучше использовать специализированные средства языка, раскладывающие документ в нормальную DOM модель

Comment: @Mike, для данной задачи хватит и уменьшения жадности, а не использование парсера DOM размером в несколько десятков килобайт.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как уменьшить жадность?

Comment: @Максим147, в первом комментарии же написали: заменить `(.*)` на `(.*?)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сформировать регулярку:

`#\<h2\>Победители:\<\/h2\>(((?!\<h2\>).)*)\<h2\>Конец\<\/h2\>#`

И вот это часть `(((?!<h2>).)*)` означает взять все кроме той строки который внутри. В нашем случае это `<h2>`.

В регулярке экранировал `h2` потому что здесь на сайте оно понимало как тег, его можете снять.

А вот [тут](https://regex101.com/r/Dz3Ryc/1) можете посмотреть работу регулярки.