# Как сделать, чтобы выражения в кавычках не находились?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
(?:\b|\.|\s)+(d{1,4}|m{1,4}|y{4}|y{2}){1}(?:\.|\s){1}(d{1,4}|m{1,4}|y{4}|y{2})?(?:\.|\s)?(d{1,4}|m{1,4}|y{4}|y{2})?(?:\.|\s)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ePV1Aq/1

Работает правильно, но находит так же совпадения внутри строк в кавычках, как это исключить?
Ну и, может, красивее написать всю эту колбасу заодно. Я пробовал сокращать за счёт повторений, но тогда ломается структура (в match вся дата, в groups отдельные элементы)

Пример:

"Форматы внутри строки в кавычках DD.MM.YYYY не учитывать:" DD.MM.YYYY "и тут dd.mm тоже"

Тут мы видим 3 совпадения, нужно, чтобы находилось только второе, т.к. первое и третье находится внутри строк в кавычках ""

Comment: Немного проясните вопрос? в каких ковичках? и что находит? что не нужно?
Здесь дайте пример строки. И то что вы хотите найти . А так вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: @RazGalstyan добавил, хотя это ясно из самого примера по ссылке, по идее

Comment: @Isaev ссылки стоит использовать исключительно как дополнение, т.к. они имеют свойство умирать, а с ними и суть вопроса и ответов. Это требование есть и в правилах емнип.

Comment: Кажется это уже тот случай когда стоит остановится и написать простой парсер, который будет и быстрее и понятнее и главное будет легок в поддержке и расширении. Как часть работы парсера можете и регэкспы использовать конечно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725666/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-html/726121#726121

Comment: @PetrAbdulin скорее да, но на крайний случай... Оставил пока вот так: https://regex101.com/r/wpwGNY/1 на последней строке только спотыкается, но не критично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ВАЖНО!!! Подойдет скорее всего только для библиотеки PCRE

---

Регулярное выражение:

```
(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*?\K|(*SKIP))+(?(DEFINE)(?'d'd{1,4}|m{1,4}|y{2,4}))(?<![dmy.])((?P>d))\.(?!\2)((?P>d))(?:\.(?!\2|\3)((?P>d)))?(?!\.?[dmy])
```

Пример работы:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ePV1Aq/2)

---

Крупноблочное описание:

- `(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*?\K|(*SKIP))` - не захватываемая группа, с получением подстроки в кавычках и сбросе захвата `\K`, иначе не позволяем курсору вернуться к текущей позиции. Сделано для строк содержащих в себе только захватываемое поле в кавычках.
- `(?(DEFINE)(?'d'd{1,4}|m{1,4}|y{2,4}))` - объявляем переменную с шаблоном для регулярного выражения, сделано что бы не писать одно и то же несколько раз а просто вызывать объявленную переменную.
- `(?<![dmy.])` - негативный просмотр назад, что бы исключить неполные совпадения (опционально).
- `((?P>d))\.(?!\2)((?P>d))` - вызываем объявленную группу, после проверяем что не идет повторение группы, что бы исключить например `MM.MM`.
- `(?:\.(?!\2|\3)((?P>d)))?` - необязательная группа для третьей части, но перед захватом проверяем что не было совпадения с предыдущими группами при значениях: `MM.DD.MM` или `MM.DD.DD`.

Comment: великолепно отрабатывает, спасибо добрый человек! yyy только вроде не бывает, потому я отдельно проверял 2 и 4, но это я сам поправлю... Delphi дружит с PCRE, т.ч. всё сошлось!